# Getting object id from enterprise application "Azure Key Vault"with Terraform does not work

Tags: azure, terraform

when I try to get the object id of the existing Azure enterprise application "Azure Key Vault" with:

```
az ad sp show --id cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093
```

(See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys#service-principal-application-id )
It works! I get the correct object id. But when I try to get it with Terraform:

```
data "azuread_application" "example" {
  application_id = "cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093"
}

output "key_vault_object_id" {
  value = data.azuread_application.example.object_id
  sensitive = false
}
```

It does not work. I get:

```
No applications found matching filter: "appId eq 'cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093'"
```

Does someone has an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the `AzureRM` provider and your CLI using the same configuration and credentials?

Comment: It should be the same user and credentials. I do not set the "ARM_TENANT_ID". But I think you are right that this has something to do with scope or configuration. I found out that I can find other enterprise applications with Terraform but they have a different "object ID" when I find them through Azure portal or "az cli". How can I find out more?